# Creating sql query in Hibernate 3.3.2 when a class is mapped to two different tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an entity class (Agreement) that is mapped to two tables (e.g Agreement and AgreementHistory) (they are distinguished by attributes "entity-name" and "table" in  node in hbm mapping file). When I invoke the code below get "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: .a.b.c.Agreement

```
public List findActiveSiteAgreement(final String siteId, final String customerId, final Date currentDate) {     

    return (List) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {

        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

             SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(
                     "SELECT sa.* " +
                     "FROM SiteAgreement sa, AgreementHeader ah " +
                     "WHERE sa.siteAgreement_id = ah.siteAgreement_id " +
                     "AND sa.mainBaseStationSite_id=:siteId " +
                     "AND ah.partner_id=:customerId " +
                     "AND NVL(ah.expiryDate, SYSDATE+1)>SYSDATE AND NVL(ah.maintainedManually,0) = 0"
             );

             //query.addEntity(SiteAgreement.class);
             query.addEntity("SiteAgreement");
             query.setParameter("siteId", new String(siteId));
             query.setParameter("customerId", new String(customerId));

             List result = query.list();

             return result;
        }
```

When I invoke saveOrUpdate method I can specify which entity name I want to use but how to handle select queries in hibernate in this case?

Here is SiteAgreement.hbm.xml

```
    <hibernate-mapping package="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain">
  <class name="SiteAgreement" entity-name="SiteAgreement" table="SiteAgreement">  
    <id name="id" column="siteagreement_id">
      <generator class="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain.LegacyIdGenerator">
        <param name="prefix">cn</param>
      </generator> 
    </id>

    <property name="currency_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="freeText" length="2000"/>
    <property name="partnerToBeInvoiced" length="35"/>
    <property name="replacedAgreement_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="mainBaseStationSite_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="transactiontag" precision="38" scale="0"/>
    <property name="agreementNumberOld" length="50"/>
    <property name="paymentPeriod"/>
    <property name="paymentRuleText" length="250"/>
    <property name="offer_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="manuallyPriced" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="changed"/>
    <property name="changedBy" length="35"/>
    <property name="created"/>
    <property name="createdBy" length="35"/>
    <property name="inSharedUse" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="paymentType" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="ubResponsiblePerson_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="partnerToBeInvoicedAddress" length="35"/>
    <property name="purchaseOrderNumber" length="35"/>
    <property name="invoiceType_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="invoicedUntil"/>
    <property name="previousInvoicedUntil"/>
    <property name="firstInvoicingDate"/>
    <property name="invoicingSuspended" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="pricingType_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="siteLocation_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="propertyRentPercent" precision="5" scale="2"/>
    <property name="retrospective_running_date" />

    <one-to-one name="agreementHeader" 
        class="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain.AgreementHeader" 
        entity-name="AgreementHeader" 
        property-ref="siteAgreement" 
        fetch="join" 
        cascade="all"/>

    <!-- added "delete-orphan" > -->
    <set name="agreementLines" inverse="true" fetch="join" cascade="all,delete-orphan" >
      <key column="siteAgreement_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain.AgreementLine" entity-name="AgreementLine" />
    </set>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is SiteAgreementHistory.hmb.xml

```
    <hibernate-mapping package="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain">
  <class name="SiteAgreement" entity-name="SiteAgreementHistory" table="SiteAgreementHistory">

    <id name="id" column="siteagreement_id">
      <!-- <generator class="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain.LegacyIdGenerator">
        <param name="prefix">cn</param>
      </generator>  -->
    </id>

    <property name="currency_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="freeText" length="2000"/>
    <property name="partnerToBeInvoiced" length="35"/>
    <property name="replacedAgreement_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="mainBaseStationSite_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="transactiontag" precision="38" scale="0"/>
    <property name="agreementNumberOld" length="50"/>
    <property name="paymentPeriod"/>
    <property name="paymentRuleText" length="250"/>
    <property name="offer_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="manuallyPriced" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="changed"/>
    <property name="changedBy" length="35"/>
    <property name="created"/>
    <property name="createdBy" length="35"/>
    <property name="inSharedUse" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="paymentType" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="ubResponsiblePerson_id" length="35"/>
    <property name="partnerToBeInvoicedAddress" length="35"/>
    <property name="purchaseOrderNumber" length="35"/>
    <property name="invoiceType_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="invoicedUntil"/>
    <property name="previousInvoicedUntil"/>
    <property name="firstInvoicingDate"/>
    <property name="invoicingSuspended" precision="1" scale="0"/>
    <property name="pricingType_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="siteLocation_tid" length="35"/>
    <property name="propertyRentPercent" precision="5" scale="2"/>
    <property name="retrospective_running_date" />

    <one-to-one name="agreementHeader" 
        class="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain.AgreementHeader" 
        entity-name="AgreementHeaderHistory" 
        property-ref="siteAgreement" 
        cascade="all" 
        fetch="join" />

    <set name="agreementLines" inverse="true" fetch="join" cascade="all">
      <key column="siteAgreement_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="lt.webmedia.unibase.conan.domain.AgreementLine" 
        entity-name="AgreementLineHistory" />
    </set>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have something like this:

```
<class name="package.Agreement" entity-name="entity1" table="agreements">
    ....
</class>


<class name="package.Agreement" entity-name="entity2" table="agreement_history">
    ....
</class>
```

Please try next:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(someSqlQuery);
query.addEntity("entity1"); //value of attribute 'entity-name' (case-sensitive)
query.setParameter("id", new String(id));
List result = query.list();
```

Comment: Actually I did that but the result was the same.

Comment: @kamilx2 It seems like it should work. Could you provide your mapping and sql query?